# Having a bit of a nightmare with Regex and a web page

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I am using Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows Vista 64 bit. I am trying to use Scrapy with Regex to parse all the content of an item on the following [page](http://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/Seasons/3853) called 'DataStore.prime(\'standings\'. If I use the code:

```
regex = re.compile('DataStore\.prime\(\'standings\', { stageId: \d+ }.*', re.S)
        match2 = re.search(regex, response.body).group()
        match3 = str(match2)
        match3 = match3.replace('<a class="w h"', '').replace('<a class="w a"', '').replace('<a class="d h"', '') \
                 .replace('<a class="d a"', '').replace('<a class="l h"', '').replace('<a class="l a"', '') \
                 .replace('title=', '')
        print match3
```

I get everything on the page, after where the Regex is found. Which is not what I want. I only want the data stored within the item. I have also tried:

```
regex = re.compile(r'\[\[.*?\].*')

        match2 = re.search(regex, response.body).group()
        match3 = str(match2)
        match3 = match3.replace('<a class="w h"', '').replace('<a class="w a"', '').replace('<a class="d h"', '') \
                 .replace('<a class="d a"', '').replace('<a class="l h"', '').replace('<a class="l a"', '') \
                 .replace('title=', '')
        print match3
```

This returns the first sub section in the 'Datastore.prime' item I am interested in, up to the first closing ']'. This method is not pointing the Regex to the item I am interested on the page. I think what I need is a hybrid of the two. I have tried using a final Regex of:

```
regex = re.compile('DataStore\.prime\(\'standings\', { stageId: \d+ } \[\[.*?\]\]\);.*', re.S)
```

But this now returns a different part of the page entirely. I'm almost there with it, but I can't quite get the last bit right.

Can anyone assist?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Here is some sample script from what I am trying to scrape:

```
DataStore.prime('standings', { stageId: 7794 }, [[Some sample stats here],[[Some sample stats here],[[Some sample stats here]]);
```

Please note in the above example the 'StageId: 7794' is a dynamic variable that will change from page to page where this data structure is encountered and thus cannot be included in any kind of regex or other parsing method.

Comment: We're going to need a sample input to help here.

Comment: @AdamSmith ok will amend the question now.

Comment: "nightmare with regex and a web page" - most redundant title ever. Stephan King could write a novel starting with that premise. The battleground is littered with people who tried to parse HTML with regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is interested, what eventually resolved this was the following:

```
regex = re.compile('DataStore\.prime\(\'standings\', { stageId: \d+ }, \[\[.*?\]\]?\)?;', re.S)

        match2 = re.search(regex, response.body).group()
        match3 = str(match2)
        match3 = match3.replace('<a class="w h"', '').replace('<a class="w a"', '').replace('<a class="d h"', '') \
                 .replace('<a class="d a"', '').replace('<a class="l h"', '').replace('<a class="l a"', '') \
                 .replace('title=', '')
        print match3
```

The problem was that the regex was matching multiple instances of the final ']' bracket and the ')'. By specifying the '?' I am now only returning 0-1 instances of those characters, which means only what I want is scraped.

Answer (score 3):

Don't parse webpages with regular expressions. Use an html parser like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Edit: to elaborate.

Regular expressions are used to recognize and manipulate regular grammars. HTML is [context-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language) and therefore cannot be correctly recognized or manipulated with regular expressions. Instead we use special parsers to manipulate HTML. BeautifulSoup is one of the more popular python html parsers.

Comment: Enjoy the upvotes but this is more of a comment than an answer. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @andrewjohnson body = response.xpath('DataStore.prime\('standings', { stageId:').extract() throws up a syntax error around 'standings'?

Comment: Obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1):

It seems like I've seen dozens of questions for this website in less than a month.
Have you at least researched available information ?
For example: there's a whole memoire about this website, explaining in length how to scrape it, extract information with betting prediction algorithms, etc.

http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:655630/FULLTEXT01.pdf

Here's an excerpt:

> Using the regex matching technique described in Appendix C, we use the pattern
>   "/Datastore.prime(’standings’, { stageId: ".✩stageID."}, [([.*\n,?)+/"
>   and find the source code for the table. An example of how this looks like is given in appendix
>   C. The next step is to further extract each unique matchID from the table-source code. For
>   this, a much less complicated pattern is sufficient, because we know that each match’s ID-tag
>   is inside an HTML hyperlink, and each hyperlink uses the match-ID as an attribute. For
>   example, the following may be a hyperlink contained in the line containing fixtures Arsenal
>   21are involved in: